# interpolate javascript if statement into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a javascript file I currently have some HTML saved into a variable.
However I only want to display the middle section of the HTML on a condition. See the `if code.length == 1`.

```
var html = `<div class="flex justify-between p-3 border-b border-blue-200" id=${this.id}><div> <h5 class="font-bold text-blue-700 text-sm mb-1 pr-2"> ${Name}</h5> <p class="text-sm text-blue-500"> if (Code.length == 1) { <span class="font-semibold mr-1"><%= t("common.code") %></span> <span>  </span> } </p></div></div>`
```

However I can't seem to get this working. Is this possible?

Comment: This line is too long to be maintainable. Break the string up in to several pieces and append only the bits you need to.

Comment: Hmm, on second thougts, you seem to have an ASP tag in there. Why are you doing this in JavaScript when it could be so much easier in the ASP

Comment: Does the id value in `id=${this.id}` contain quotes? If not, you might want to wrap it to be safe.

Comment: I would say use variables. You use variables to be rendered in the snippet so why not just add your own for the span content? I posted an example as answer below.

Comment: [Maybe helpfull](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nmqf7o?file=script.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is too long to be maintainable. Break it up so you can see what's going on.

```
var html = `<div class="flex justify-between p-3 border-b border-blue-200" id=${this.id}><div> <h5 class="font-bold text-blue-700 text-sm mb-1 pr-2"> ${Name}</h5> <p class="text-sm text-blue-500">`;

if (Code.length == 1) {
  html += `<span class="font-semibold mr-1"><%= t("common.code") %></span> <span>  </span>`;
}

html += `</p></div></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a variable

In your HTML snippet you are already using variables. Why not stick to that by making the content a variable. See snippet below with values added as an example using a variable `content`.

This part seems prepared server-side: `<%= t("common.code") %>`. You know how to do that yourself I'm assuming.

```js
let Code = 'K';
let id = '5'; // this.id;
let Name = 'Herring';

var content = Code.length == 1 ? `<span class="font-semibold mr-1"><%= t("common.code") %></span>` : '';

var html = `<div class="flex justify-between p-3 border-b border-blue-200" id="${id}"><div>
  <h5 class="font-bold text-blue-700 text-sm mb-1 pr-2">${Name}</h5>
  <p class="text-sm text-blue-500">${content}</p>
</div></div>`;

console.log(html);
```